# Is there a way to detect if the browser window is visible to the user?

Tags: javascript, browser, visibility

Is there a way to detect if the browser window is visible to the user? I know this has been asked before. However, the answers I have seen suffer from the following problems:

1. Using `visibilityChange` event. The problem with this approach is that (at least on a Mac) when one uses cmd+tab to switch between applications, this event is not fired.
2. Using `onBlur` and `onFocus` events. These solve the above problem. However, these also fire when a page's visibility does not change. For example, if the browser is open in one half of the screen and another application is open in the other half, then switching between these will cause these events to fire; even though the user has the browser window visible all the time.
3. Using `onPageShow` and `onPageHide` events - these appear quite useless for the task of visibility. For example, `onPageHide` does not fire either when the page is minimized, or when cmd+tab is used to switch to another application that occupies the whole window.

What is the ideal solution for checking whether the page is visible to the user given the above issues?

Thank you.

Comment: In which cases could the `window` would not be visible?

Comment: @guest271314 that seems clearly stated. Did you read all of the question?

Comment: @hcoat Yes, read Question. Though still not certain about what "is visible" includes or excludes? If `window` is open, though `display` set to `none` at `<body>` element, should `window` be considered "visible"? If `window` dimensions are `1px` `width` , `1px` `height`, should `window` be considered "visible"? Can you include examples of "visible", "not visible" at Question?

Comment: no, the browser doesn't know where on the desktop the window is or if there's another app in front of it, etc. All it really knows is if it's the current window or not.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Visible for me meant that when a user is looking at her screen, she can see at least some of the contents of the window. I admit, I did not think of a threshold level of pixels that would differentiate between visibility and non-visibility. For the sake of precision let us say that yes, even  if the user can see a 1px by 1px window (in the sense that it is not completely hidden by another application or tab) then we will call it visible. If it is completely hidden, then it is not visible. With that defined, is there a better solution than those listed above?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use setIterval polling and document.hidden?

nice wrapper [Visibility.js](https://github.com/ai/visibilityjs)

Comment: The poster is obviously aware of the Page Visibility API, the question pertains to mac+cmd+tab not triggering the event.   If the events are not triggered my question is if the document values indicate this from simple polling as a fallback -- I'm not answering the question but asking if they could try this ------ should this have been done as comment instead?

Comment: Most of the time I cannot replicate the environment to reproduce the issue and 9 or 10 times my suggestions lead to partial solutions --- I will enter these as comments in the future, thanks for the feedback